# referrer policy header not working apache .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-headers, referrer-policy

using securityheaders.io website, I can't get referrer policy header recognized in apache .htaccess.

This is my code in htaccess

```
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Referrer-Policy "no-referrer"
 </IfModule>
```

The site still says missing referrer policy. Is this not the right code to use?

Comment: did you set `AllowOverride All`?

Answer (score 6):

You must add like this in your htaccess file

```
Header always set Referrer-Policy "same-origin"
```

Answer (score -2):

Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Referrer-Policy: origin
Referrer-Policy: origin-when-cross-origin
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Referrer-Policy: unsafe-url

Referrer-Policy: same-origin is usally recommended.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @PatrikI where dows is said that is "usally recommended"?

Answer (score -3):

This worked for me:

```
Header always set Referrer-Policy "no-referrer"
```